# Is there anyway to move an object up/down/left/right without using pixels in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a 3D effect button (it's actually a decorated-link) with HTML&CSS, and I need a way to move the object upwards and downwards without using any kind of pixels/cm/mm(absolute units) to specify the length to the top so it can have a 3D effect on hover no matter the position.

I already tried to change the padding and the box-shadow, but it just wouldn't look like what I wanted. The code below is my code to change the padding (which failed).

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
```

```css
.button{
  display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:monospace;
  color:blue;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  box-shadow:5px 10px grey;
  border-radius:15px;
  position:absolute;
  transition:ease 0.5s;
}
.button:hover{
  background-color:yellow;
  color:darkgreen;
  box-shadow:8px 15px grey;
  padding:8px 15px 5px 10px;
}
```

The result didn't look really 3D, but if there IS a way to change the "top" and "left" attribute in CSS without using absolute units, the problem would be solved. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Have you considered using ```percentages```, ```em``` or ```rem```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really do you want to achive ?

Do you mean that you don't want to position your button to the outer container when moving and object ? if so then you could use

```
.css{
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px
}
```

Then element will be positioning itself from the place where it belongs

Comment: THAT SOLVES MY PROBLEM! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mhmdabed11/pen/JgmvqN) for your case. What you can do is , for example,  use `transform:translateY(-10%)`. In this way, you will not be using `px`, `em` and `rem`.